# Defining map control-Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am having difficulty understanding the following error message.[image]

[image]

```
    var okombahe_erven = L.tileLayer.betterWms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Erongo/wms", {
    layers: 'okombahe_erven',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: '',
  });

  var map = L.map('map', {
    zoomControl:true,
    zoom: 14,
    maxZoom:25,
    minZoom:5,
    center: new L.LatLng(-21.3665370941162, 15.3731527328491),

    layers: [OSM, okombahe_erven]
  });

  var baseMaps = {
    "OpenStreetMap": OSM,
    "ESRI  World Imnagery": Esri_WorldImagery
  };
  var overlayMaps = {

    "Zonning": okombahe_erven,
  };
  L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

var logo = L.control({position: 'topright'});
logo.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'logo');
    div.innerHTML = "<img src='./images/North_Arrow.svg' height='50px'/></a>";
    return div;
};

map.on("browser-print-start", function(e){

    for (let key in control.getOverlays()) {
        function printer(layer_name) {
            console.log(layer_name);
            layer_name.addTo(e.printMap);

        }

        if (control.getOverlays()[key] !== true) {
            continue;
        }
        var map_legend = key.concat('_legend');
        okombahe_erven_legend.addTo(e.printMap);
        logo.addTo(e.printMap);

    }

});
var customActionToPrint;
customActionToPrint = function (context, mode) {
    return function () {
        window.alert(" Select Specific area to print the map!");
        context._printCustom(mode);
    }
};

L.control.browserPrint({
    title: '',
    documentTitle: '',

    closePopupsOnPrint: true,
    printModes: [
        L.control.browserPrint.mode("Alert", "User specified print action", "A6", customActionToPrint, false),
        L.control.browserPrint.mode.landscape(),
        "Portrait"
    ],
    manualMode: false
}).addTo(map);

  var okombahe_erven_legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
    okombahe_erven_legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
        div.innerHTML +=
        '<span><img src='+""+' height="20px" align="top";>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></br>';
    return div;
    };  


  okombahe_erven_legend.addTo(map);
    map.on('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) {

    if (eventLayer.name === 'Zonning') {
        this.removeControl(okombahe_erven_legend);
        okombahe_erven_legend.addTo(this);
    }
            else { 
        this.removeControl(zoning_legend);

    }
});
```

Comment: This simply means that object `control` is not defined, or to be more accurate, is not defined in such a way to be accessible to event processing function. What should this `control` object be?

Comment: I believe control is not defined in a way that is accessing to event processing function because I used the same printing on another map that is structured differently and it works fine. I have updated the code.

Comment: What your are missing is declaration of print `control` object when defining it: `var control = L.control.browserPrint({ ...`.

Comment: You are deleting comments that were later answered by comment from somebody else. Without your comment, answering comment of course has no meaning. That's not correct practice, please refrain from it in the future.